# How to detect re-select event and navigate to the first page in the cupetinotab in flutter

Tags: ios, flutter, dart

I created bottom navigation for iOS using CupetinoTabBar in flutter and I'd like to detect re-select tab event and go back to the its first page.
Is there any way to implement the function?
For iOS, it's a pretty common function but I don't know how to do it.
The code is below.

Thank you in advance.

```
class _MainTabScreenState extends State<MainTabScreen> {
  final List<Widget> _pages = [FeedScreen(), Feed2Screen(), HomeScreen()];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CupertinoTabScaffold(
      tabBar: CupertinoTabBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
        items: <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.home)),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.movie)),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.person)),
        ],
      ),
      tabBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        return CupertinoTabView(
          builder: (ctx) {
            return _pages[index];
          },
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```